# ¿Actualizar tabla usando jQuery y controlador en Spring?

Tags: jquery, spring

Lo que busco es que al dar clic en el botón se me actualice la tabla de comentarios asíncronamente, es decir, me cargue una función jquery que me actualice una tabla en el JSP. Os dejo el código, pues actualmente me salta el "alert" de error:

Controlador:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updatecomments") 
public  @ResponseBody
String update(@RequestParam int lolMatchId){    
    Collection<CommentMatch> cm= commentMatchService.findAllByLolMatchId(lolMatchId);
    List<CommentMatch> cmatch = new ArrayList<CommentMatch>(cm);
    Collections.reverse(cmatch);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(cmatch);
}
```

Jsp:

```
<form method="post">  
 <input type="button" value="Refresh" id = "b" onclick="searchAjax()" />
</form> 

<display:table name="commentsMatch" id="c" requestURI="lolMatch/match.do"     pagesize="5" class="displaytag" >

<display:column property="customer.name"  />
<display:column property="description"  />

</display:table>

<script type="text/javascript" src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function searchAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            dataType : "json",
            url : "/${pageContext.request.contextPath}/updatecomments",
            headers : {
            'Accept' : 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
            },
            type: 'POST',
            success : function(response) {   

             $.each( response,function(key, comment) {
                 var htmlrow ="<tr><td>" + comment.description + "</td></tr>";         
                 $('#c').append(htmlrow);
             });
         },      
         error : function(){
             alert("error");
         }
     });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Primero hay un error en `$('c').append(htmlrow);` ya que debería ser `$('#c').append(htmlrow);` pues te refieres a un ID, segundo: ¿cual es el error que da?, puedes agregar el resultado de la consola modificando la función on error ..?

Comment: Es decir, algo asi `error : function(e){ console.log(e); }`

Comment: realmente tenia $('#c'), se me quito en algún lapsus.. voy a ver lo de function(e){ console.log(e); } y te digo

Comment: jejeje.. ok pasa. manda mensaje cuando lo hallas editado

Comment: pues ahí te dejo el error... http://i65.tinypic.com/4gkbxe.png no entra en la función y me crea el windows alert

Comment: @Fran-US no se ve la imagen del error

Comment: pulsa en zoom (izquierda) y aparece la imagen, aunque es lo mismo, no entra en la función

Comment: verifica que la parte java es correcta haciendo una llamada a tu Controllador via PostMan o directamente en el navegador, al menos así podras localizar si el problema esta en la parte java o en el cliente

Comment: la vista me funciona perfectamente, tiene puesto para que muestre el video de youtube, recoge los comentarios y los muestra, puedo escribir nuevos comentarios, ... El problema es cuando pulso actualizar, me sale la ventana de error status: parseerror, error : unexpected token <

Comment: Por favor adjunta las trazas de error que se producen, tambien adjunta la configuracion de Spring MVC que estas utilizando

Answer (score 0):

El método en tu controller esta esperando un parámetro llamado **lolMatchId** de tipo int.

En tu llamada de ajax no veo por ningún lado el atributo **data**, supongo que eso te esta causando el problema.